# Rspec feature test: Cannot visit a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have rspec features tests that are all failing because i cannot visit the indicated path. They all seems to be stuck at the root path after logging in. A screenshot shows that the page still remains on the root path. The test steps work on the browser, which means that the routing is correct. Any ideas?

I am getting the below error message for the test:

> Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?

**Extract of my feature spec test:**

```
describe 'follow users' do

    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:friend) }

  describe "Managing received friend request", js: true do

    let!(:request) { Friendship.create(user_id: other_user.id, friend_id: user.id, accepted: false) }

    before do
       login_as(user, :scope => :user)
       visit followers_path
    end

    it 'friend request disappear once user clicks accept' do
      click_on "Accept"
      wait_for_ajax
      expect(current_path).to eq(followers_path)
      expect(page).to have_css(".pending-requests", text: "You have 0 pending friend requests")
      expect(page).to_not have_css(".pending-requests", text: other_user.name)
      expect(page).to_not have_link("Accept")
      expect(page).to_not have_link("Decline")
  end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this approach to wait for all the ajax requests to finish:

```
def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
    until active == 0
      active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
    end
  end
end
```

Taken from: [Wait for ajax with capybara 2.0](https://coderwall.com/p/aklybw/wait-for-ajax-with-capybara-2-0)

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but the use of wait_for_ajax helper is causing  the error message Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero? i have tried to use expect(page).to have_content() instead, but screenshot still shows root path page

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: i'm using 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you're calling 'wait_for_ajax' either on a page that doesn't include jQuery or at a time when it hasn't yet been loaded.  The solution is to stop using `wait_for_ajax` and instead use the Capybara expectations/matchers as designed. There are very very few cases where `wait_for_ajax` is actually needed and even then it's usually a sign of bad UI decisions (no indication to the user something is happening). You should also not be using the `eq` matcher with `current_path` and should be using the Capybara provided `have_current_path` matcher instead since it has waiting/retrying behavior like all of the Capybara provided matchers.

```
it 'friend request disappear once user clicks accept' do
  click_on "Accept"
  expect(page).to have_current_path(followers_path)
  expect(page).to have_css(".pending-requests", text: "You have 0 pending friend requests")
  expect(page).to_not have_css(".pending-requests", text: other_user.name)
  expect(page).to_not have_link("Accept")
  expect(page).to_not have_link("Decline")
end
```

If that doesn't work for you, then either the button click isn't actually triggering page changes (check your test log), your `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` isn't set high enough for the hardware you're testing on, your `login_as` statement isn't actually logging in the user (although then I would expect the click on the accept button to fail), or you have a bug in your app.

If it's that `login_as` isn't actually logging in then make sure the server being used to run the AUT is running in the same process as the tests, if you're using `puma` that means making sure in the output it doesn't say it' s running in clustered mode.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole, i have removed wait_for_ajax and change to have_current_path, but my test is sill failing. I have many other tests failing and exhibiting strange behaviour after ajax calls, either not executing a click_on or stuck at root_path (they are all failing now when i have tested them a while back and they were all passing). I am aware that expect(page).to have_content should be used instead of wait_for_ajax for ajax calls. Could i trouble you with having a look at my rspec tests in my github repo: https://github.com/dianameow/diana-portal/tree/master/spec

Comment: I think i have scoped down the problem to capybara's click_on not working in all my tests

Comment: @doyz I've tried running your tests and a lot of them with different errors like errors about missing methods on nil,etc. However running just the one test you asked about alone and it passes just fine for me, not sure what you have going on, I'd recommend deleting and reinstalling the capybara-webkit gem

Comment: @doyz Also you probably want to update Capybara - 2.7.1 is pretty ancient at this point.

Comment: @doyz I went and tried your latest commit - which fails due to JS errors in the page.  Specifically your pages.js is missing a `})` somewhere in there.  In test mode when all the JS gets concatenated an error in a single file can stop the rest of the file from being processed.  In dev mode an error in one file only stops that file from being processed.  Here it's preventing the rails ujs stuff from being loaded, so when you click the "Follow" button it's submitting a get rather than a post, and then your app catches the 404 and redirects to /  (maybe don't catch the 404s in dev/test mode)

Comment: @boyz Also configuring capybara-webkit to raise JS errors would have caught this too - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration